# Do I need to explain to my office manager how I got a key to the business park?

Tags: manager, employer

I work in a business park. One way to access this business park is via a pedestrian gate using a key.  Normally no one uses this route and it hasn't been open to the public for many many years.

I have requested the business park owners if I could get a key so that from time to time I could walk to work. They gave me one.

Now my office manager is asking why I have this key. I do not feel its any of her business, but is it professional to tell her to mind her own business in this situation?

Comment: Please clarify the relationship between your employer and the business park owner - are they the same entity, or is your employer merely one of many businesses in the park?

Comment: It is a legitimate question. Getting huffy at being asked legitimate questions is counterproductive to your career. In the long run it is unimportant, save your stronger responses for important things. Perhaps she would pick at you less if you stop being and acting annoyed by everything she says to you.

Comment: *Where do I stand on telling her to mind her own business* - how is distribution of keys to the office **not** the office manager's business? Answer her question, you asked the owners if you could get a key and they gave you one.

Comment: Have you considered that maybe she is thinking you took one from the company or had one of the companies duplicated?

Comment: @Chad alternatively maybe the manager also wants a key.  I sense a 'piss poor communication' problem here.

Comment: Why can't you say "I asked the business park owners and they gave me one"? Maybe your office manager wants to use the some shortcut as you do? It's about the same as my manager asking which train I use to get to work; I have actually asked my manager exactly that question and got a reply.

Comment: Telling someone (literally) to *mind their own business* is **never** professional.

Comment: And you should also answer the question Matt Holmes asked under NVoigt's answer: do you have a supervisor/subordinate relationship between you and the office manager.

Comment: Why do you want to keep it secret?

Comment: @TheMonkeyMan  This is a couple of years old.  How did this situation turn out?

Answer (score 50):

I cannot see any harm coming from simply telling the truth. It was convenient for you to have a key; you asked for it, and you got it.

If your superior is really trying to pick on you, the easiest way to make it hard for her is not providing any attack surface. Be helpful, truthful and productive. You did nothing wrong. Smile and cooperate.

Comment: Lots of reasons why this is a perfectly reasonable request. Maybe she wants to walk to work too. Maybe she wants to give other workers the same opportunity you have.

Comment: I've never worked at place where the office manager was my supervisor. Generally office managers oversee facilities (which this covers) and executive assistants. I don't think there is a supervisor/subordinate relationship here, unless I am missing something?

Answer (score 15):

I wouldn't (tell her to mind her own business), as it may actually be her business.

It may be in the tenancy agreement between your company and the business park that they have a responsibility around security/replacement of these keys.  The person who issued it to you could be inept/untrained/assuming you've had permission from your company, and the company may well be liable if you walk off the job and take the key with you.

I'd just approach it in a business-like fashion, if it isn't something untoward, you shouldn't be all secretive about it.

Comment: your answer seems contradictory "I wouldn't, as it may well be in their interests." followed by "if it isn't something untoward, you shouldn't be all secretive about it." - Could you please clarify

Comment: I wouldn't "tell(ing) her to mind her own business" as it likely is the business of the OP's company

Answer (score 0):

Your manager might have it in for you, but generally managers want their people to be successful because that makes the manager successful.  Your attitude that it's none of your manager's business seems to indicate you don't like people having power and authority.  If nobody goes through a particular gate it would absolutely be the manager's duty to better understand this odd arrangement.

Your best course of action would be to meet your manager in private and say, "I'm sorry if I did something wrong. I wanted to be able to walk to work quickly through that gate.  I think maybe I should have come to you first to make sure it was ok to do this.  Here's the key... what do you want me to do?  Whatever you decide is ok with me; I understand you have a different perspective that I don't have."